# ActionController::ParameterMissing in CotizacionsController#create param is missing or the value is empty: cotizacion

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, ruby

El contexto de la pregunta es el siguiente:

1. Generé la entidad `Cotizacions`, a través de `scaffold`. Se creó la vista, modelo y controlador correspondiente: *cotizacions_controller.rb*, *cotizacion.rb* y vistas (*_cotizacion.json.jbuilder*, *_form.html.erb*, *edit.html.erb*, *index.html.erb*, *new.html.erb*).
2. Se instala template, creative de *Bootstrap*. Se crea controlador y vistas correspondientes: *creatives_controller.rb* y vistas (*index.html.erb*, *_header.html.erb*, etc.).

Lo primero que se realizó fue ocupar el formulario generado en la vista de `cotizacions` *_form.html.erb*. Desde la vista se `creatives` archivo *_header.html.erb*, utilizando el siguiente codigo:

```
<header>
  <div class="header-content">
    <div class="header-content-inner">
      <h1>Negocia tu Auto</h1>
      <p>Somos una empresa especialista......</p>
      <%= render :partial =>'cotizacions/form' , locals: { cotizacion:@cotizacion } %>
    </div>
  </div>  
</header>
```

El problema es que al gatillar el evento desde la vista `cotizacions`, recibo el siguiente mensaje:

> ActionController::ParameterMissing in CotizacionsController#create
>   param is missing or the value is empty: cotizacion

El controlador de `cotizacions` es el siguiente:

```
class CotizacionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cotizacion, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @cotizacions = Cotizacion.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @cotizacion = Cotizacion.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @cotizacion = Cotizacion.new(cotizacion_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cotizacion.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cotizacion, notice: 'Cotizacion was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cotizacion }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cotizacion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cotizacion.update(cotizacion_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cotizacion, notice: 'Cotizacion was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cotizacion }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @cotizacion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @cotizacion.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cotizacions_url, notice: 'Cotizacion was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  def set_cotizacion
    @cotizacion = Cotizacion.find(params[:id])
  end

  def cotizacion_params
    params.require(:cotizacion).permit(
      :patente, :marca, :modelo, :kilometraje, :correo, :telefono, :comentarios, 
      :abs, :aire_acondicionado, :airbag, :cant, :velocidad_crucero, :aux, :aux1
    )
  end
end
```

He intentado corregir el problema agregando el siguiente código el controlador de `creatives`;

```
class CreativesController < ApplicationController
  layout "creative"
  match "/cotizacions" => "cotizacions#create", :via => [:post]
end
```

Pero ahora recibo el siguiente error:

> undefined method `match' for CreativesController:Class Did you mean?
>   catch

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_with(model: cotizacion) do |form| %>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="field">
          <%= form.text_field :patente, 
                              placeholder: "Patente", 
                              id: :car_patente, 
                              class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-inline">
          <%= form.select :marca, 
                          options_for_select([["SUBARU", "t"], ["KIA", "s"]], id: :car_marca), 
                          prompt: "Marca", 
                          class: "combobox form-control",
                          name: "inline"%>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="field">
          <%= form.text_field :modelo, 
                              id: :car_modelo, 
                              placeholder: "Modelo Ej: Yaris, i10",
                              class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="field">
          <%= form.select :kilometraje,
                          options_for_select([["0 - 10.0000", "t"], ["10.0001 - 20.0000", "s"]], id: :car_kilometraje),
                          prompt: "Kilometraje",
                          class: "combobox form-control",
                          name: "inline" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="field">
          <%= form.email_field :correo, 
                               id: :car_correo,
                               placeholder: "ejemplo@mail.com",
                               class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="field">
          <%= form.telephone_field :telefono,
                                   id: :car_telefono,
                                   placeholder: "Télefono",
                                   class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h2 class="text-center">Seleccione Equipamiento</h2> 
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"> 
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <%= form.check_box :abs, id: :car_abs %>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...", placeholder="ABS">
          </div><!-- /input-group -->
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <%= form.check_box :aire_acondicionado, id: :car_aire_acondicionado %>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...", placeholder="Aire Acondicionado">
          </div><!-- /input-group -->
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <%= form.check_box :airbag, id: :car_airbag %>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...", placeholder="Airbag">
          </div><!-- /input-group -->
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <%= form.check_box :velocidad_crucero, id: :car_velocidad_crucero %>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...", placeholder="Velocidad Crucero">
          </div><!-- /input-group -->
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset">
        <div class="actions">
          <%= form.submit  class: 'btn btn-success btn-lg', value: 'Tasar su Vehículo' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'creatives/index'
  resources :cotizacions
  post 'creatives/index', to: 'cotizacions#create
end
```

log:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: cotizacion):

app/controllers/cotizacions_controller.rb:74:in `cotizacion_params'
app/controllers/cotizacions_controller.rb:29:in `create'
Started POST "/creatives/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-29 15:01:27 -0400
Processing by CotizacionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vu6ARii6s6IjRMeN7TWM1vmh/KKNja5l37EFnlfN7B0YtwvVq/bzIb9qbYTRuJDh8FwuZCgu1u2dvD4B0BPlog==", "patente"=>"", "marca"=>"", "modelo"=>"", "kilometraje"=>"", "correo"=>"", "telefono"=>"", "abs"=>"0", "aire_acondicionado"=>"0", "airbag"=>"0", "velocidad_crucero"=>"0", "commit"=>"Tasar su Vehículo"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: cotizacion):

app/controllers/cotizacions_controller.rb:74:in `cotizacion_params'
app/controllers/cotizacions_controller.rb:29:in `create'
Started POST "/creatives/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-29 15:01:28 -0400
Processing by CotizacionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vu6ARii6s6IjRMeN7TWM1vmh/KKNja5l37EFnlfN7B0YtwvVq/bzIb9qbYTRuJDh8FwuZCgu1u2dvD4B0BPlog==", "patente"=>"", "marca"=>"", "modelo"=>"", "kilometraje"=>"", "correo"=>"", "telefono"=>"", "abs"=>"0", "aire_acondicionado"=>"0", "airbag"=>"0", "velocidad_crucero"=>"0", "commit"=>"Tasar su Vehículo"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms
```

Comment: No es necesario modificar tus rutas, el problema está rn la forma. ¿Podrías mostrar el código de _cotizacions/_form.html.erb_? También sería de gran ayuda incluir el log con los parámetros enviados (donde aparece el primer error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer estás generando la forma en `index` (i.e. *index.html.erb*) en lugar de hacerlo en `new` (i.e. *new.html.erb*), lo que ocasiona que `@cotizacion` sea `nil`; como resultado `form_with` no reconoce el modelo y, por ende, no agrupa correctamente.

Puedes solucionarlo de varias formas, pero la más sencilla (en mi opinion) es agregar el atributo `scope` en `form_width` para especificar que la forma siempre agrupe con `cotizacion`; por ejemplo:

```
<%= form_with(model: cotizacion, scope: :cotizacion ) do |form| %>
```

Ahora, al enviarse la forma, se enviarán los parámetros agrupados en `cotizacion`; algo similar a:

```
Parameters: {
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"...==",
  "cotizacion"=>{
    "patente"=>"", 
    "marca"=>"", 
    "modelo"=>"", 
    "kilometraje"=>"", 
    "correo"=>"", 
    "telefono"=>"", 
    "abs"=>"0", 
    "aire_acondicionado"=>"0", 
    "airbag"=>"0", 
    "velocidad_crucero"=>"0"
  },
  "commit"=>"Tasar su Vehículo"
}
```

De esta forma el parámetro `cotizacion` estará siempre presente y, por lo tanto, el método `cotizacion_params` ya no arrojará el error.

Comment: Funciono!!!! Muchas gracias, ahora tengo que ver como mostrar el msje de éxito o rechazo, en la vista de creatives al momento de insertar una cotización.

Comment: @SebastianCamposDavila Que bien! Te recomiendo abrir una nueva pregunta en caso que tengas problemas para mostrar el mensaje de éxito/rechazo. Y no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada (dando clic a la paloma). Suerte!